# Should we say two takbeer on the very moment we join the Imam during congregration?

Tags: salat, takbir

What should we do when join the salat in the following cases when we are **Masbuk**:

1. while Imaam is in ***qiyam*** [standing].
2. when we find the Imaam in ***rukoo***.
3. when Imaam is in ***sajdah* or other positions***.

Should we just say the takbeer [**الله اكبر**] and join the prayers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question implies for **Case: 2** and **Case: 3**. We need to say two takbeers following one after the another if we face a situation described in the question.

The ***first takbeer*** is the mandatory *Farz* takbeer known as ***Takbeer-e-Tahreema*** (takbeerat al-ehram تكبيرة الإحرام).
`this one would be counted as the first one of the six Farz [mandatory acts] inside salat known as ARKAN`

The following takbeer i,e the ***second takbeer*** would be counted as the regular takbeers that we say while we do any movement in salat.

---

For **Case: 1** we just need to say only one takbeer and attened the salat.

---

Note: **Masbuk** means a person who is late to join the salat with the Imam and misses at least **One** rakaat.

Comment: The word rukn (plural arkan) is not common in all madhabs neither are many definitions of specific qualifications of acts. Also the answer may differ between madhabs, some may allow one takbeer others would consider it not valid!

Comment: جزاك الله خير @Medi1Saif